# How remove module name from url magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, url-rewrite

Is it possible to remove module  name through htaccess or any other way around to hide module name from url of magento 2 .i.e  `http://abcd.com/modulename/controller`

Only need to display controller name instead of the module name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a URL Rewrite.

Go to `Marketing/SEO & Search/URL Rewrites`

Then create a new rewrite, put in correct request path, which should be the path to your desired new path, and target path should be the path to your module's controller `/modulename/controller`